# Reference variable outside function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to call a value that is outside a function but an error appeared. 
This is a part of the code:

```
for element in initial_valid_pos:   
    i = 0
    g = 1
    z = -1

    def loop():

        for element2 in valid_pos[1 + i]:

            if int(element) == (int(element2) + z):
                print(element)
            if int(element) == (int(element2) + g):
                print(element)
            else:
                pass
        i = i + 1
        z = z - 1
        g = g + 1
        loop()
```

As you can see, first a give value 0 to I and so on, then I start looping inside, and while inside the loop I would like to increment the values of `i`, `z`, `g`.

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Are you defining a fuction inside a `for` loop? Sounds crazy! :) Take it out of the loop and pass those variables as parameters.

Comment: i need to write a program that find the exit path of a random maze. Giving the valid starting position, this was my only way to get the right exit path. But maybe i'm doing it wrong

Comment: Please post working code. There is no `valid_pos` and for `loop()` to execute, the call to `loop()` has to be de-indented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all please note that Python relies heavily on indentation. I guess you know that, but then you seem to have defined the `loop()` function *inside* the first `for` loop, which sounds daunting to me, to say the least (I actually don't even know if that is allowed).

Anyway you don't seem to need that in your example, so just deindent the function definition and pass those variables as parameters, such as:

```
def loop():
    for element2 in valid_pos[1 + i]:
        if int(element) == (int(element2) + z):
            print(element)
        if int(element) == (int(element2) + g):
            print(element)
        else:
            pass
        loop(i + 1, g + 1, z - 1)

for element in initial_valid_pos:   
    loop (0, 1, -1)
```

I don't guarantee that the code works as expected though, still it doesn't make much sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
def loop():

    for element2 in valid_pos[1 + i]:
```

with:

```
def loop():
    global i, g, z
    for element2 in valid_pos[1 + i]:
```